Cannot add MFA in the Entra Admin Center
I have a very small Azure subscription with only two users. This is not a big enterprise.
In the Entra admin center, I have the following authentication methods available:

However, I am not able to add them to my user, the pointed button is disabled:

What is the easiest way to add some basic MFA to my admin users?


Note that: To configure MFA for all users including admin users, you must have Privileged Authentication Administrator role assigned.


To configure MFA for only users, Authentication Administrator role is required.

I got the same issue:

Hence to resolve the error, assign active Privileged Authentication Administrator role to your user account like below:
Go to Azure Portal -> Microsoft Entra ID roles and administrators -> Privileged Authentication Administrator role -> Select -> Add assignments -> Select member -> Next -> Select Active -> Enter justification -> Assign

After assigning the role wait for few minutes to get it effected.
Now I am able to successfully add authentication methods:

If still issue persists, refer this MsDoc for more information about which role must be assigned based on the scenario
Reference:
Admin permission for MFA - Microsoft Q&A by AmanpreetSingh-MSFT
